# how many frames does OPEN CV produce?

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to capture images from a video file using OPEN CV and I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/30136402/15916156
here's the code

```
import os

def video_to_frames(video, path_output_dir):
    # extract frames from a video and save to directory as 'x.png' where 
    # x is the frame index
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    count = 0
    while vidcap.isOpened():
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        if success:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_output_dir, '%d.png') % count, image)
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    vidcap.release()

video_to_frames('../somepath/myvid.mp4', '../somepath/out')
```

now I want to have the same name, as the video name with concatenated numbers of frames.
How should I change the code?

Comment: pls try the options listed in [CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311153/python-extracting-and-saving-video-frames)

Answer (score 1):

Check string split method where you can break a string using some characters.

For instance `video.split('/')[-1]` might get you the filename.

Make it equal to `filename =  video.split('/')[-1]` and add it to:

> ((path_output_dir, filename + '%d.png') % count, image))

Comment: Thanks but here's my TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list